# Google Service Account credentials stored in AWS SecretManage

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-api-python-client, service-accounts, aws-secrets-manager

in my Aws EC2 instance, I've a python script that interacts with Google Bigquery to perform several operations.

For security reasons, I don't want to use the service account private key as a file in my project, so, I stored it in my AWS Secrets Manager.

In python, it's easy to get the key using boto3:

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
import google.oauth2
    def get_secret():       
       secret_name = "put_key_name_here"
       region_name = "put_region_name_here"
       session = boto3.session.Session()
       client = session.client(service_name='secretsmanager', region_name=region_name)
       get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(SecretId = secret_name)
       a = json.loads(get_secret_value_response['SecretString'])
       return a['credentials'] #HERE I HAVE MY CREDENTIALS STRING
```

now I need to use one of the methods of the Google client.
I can't use *from_service_account_file* but only *from_service_account_info*
https://googleapis.dev/python/google-auth/1.7.0/user-guide.html

but the code goes on error:

```
dict_secrets={}
dict_secrets["client_email"]="my_account@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
dict_secrets["token_uri"]="https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"
dict_secrets["private_key"] = get_secret() #myfunction to get the private_key
my_project='my_google_bigquery_project'
credential_bq = google.oauth2.service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(dict_secrets, scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"])
client_bq = bigquery.Client(credentials=credential_bq, project=my_project)

ValueError: No key could be detected.
```

without
`dict_secrets["private_key"]`  I received a differ error:

```
 ValueError: The private_key field was not found in the service account info
```

Where I am wrong?
Exist another way to do these operations?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/secretsmanager.html#SecretsManager.Client.get_secret_value)

The response syntax is:

```
{
    'ARN': 'string',
    'Name': 'string',
    'VersionId': 'string',
    'SecretBinary': b'bytes',
    'SecretString': 'string',
    'VersionStages': [
        'string',
    ],
    'CreatedDate': datetime(2015, 1, 1)
}
```

So you need so pull out the `'SecretString'` from the response -

```
get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(SecretId = secret_name)
secret_value = get_secret_value_response["SecretString"]
```

Also, from the [Google Service Account docs](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys), the downloaded key has the following format, where private-key is the private portion of the public/private key pair:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "project-id",
  "private_key_id": "key-id",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nprivate-key\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "service-account-email",
  "client_id": "client-id",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/service-account-email"
}
```

:

Comment: Hi @glen-carpenter thanks for the suggestion.

My code already performs these operations, to be clear:

dict_secrets["private_key"] = get_secret()

it executes:
get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value( SecretId = secret_name )
a = json.loads(get_secret_value_response['SecretString'])
return a['credentials']

so, I have the value of SecretString and I put it into the dictionary dict_secrets that I use as input for the google.oauth2.service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info

I edited my question to explain better what the code does

Comment: @gip I edited my response, it looks like it may be your key format, it needs to be in PEM format

Comment: @gip, does this mean that we have to transform the private_key as provided by google into PEM format and then save it into AWS secrets? It seems to be already in PEM fromat.

It seems to me that when retreived it cannot be parsed to JSON. Gives error.